# iOS Provision violated for watchdog scene-create using Pushkit

Tags: ios, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

## Issue

`Provision violated for watchdog scene-create: <FBSProcessResourceProvision: 0x282c3bc00; allowance: <; FBSProcessResourceAllowance; type: scheduledTime; timeValue: 0.40s>; violated: YES>`

In my Nativescript-Angular app, older iOS devices like the iPhone6 fail to launch via pushkit because watchdog terminates it. I am not doing any network actions (which seems to be the main reason for watchdog from other posts).

I created a dummy app which have the same app module, app component and all I do is import the dependencies and I can still timeout. The time value fluctuates on every run and can range from 0.01s to the timeValue is 1.0s.

*On more recent devices like the iPhone8, X and iPads I do not encounter this issue.

## Device & Nativescript Info

Nativescript Info: 
✔ Component nativescript has 4.2.4 version and is up to date. 
✔ Component tns-core-modules has 4.2.1 version and is up to date.
✔ Component tns-android has 4.2.0 version and is up to date.
✔ Component tns-ios has 4.2.0 version and is up to date.

Device: iPhone 6 using iOS 12

Built: Webpack with AOT and Uglify enabled + in production mode

I am curious to see if others have run into this issue or if anyone has any suggestions as to how I can improve the launch time and avoid the watchdog timeout.

Comment: What dependencies or plugins you are using?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem? It may be critical to know it since it happens again but in a different context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55206482/iphone-has-denied-the-launch-request-issue