# iPhone has denied the launch request issue

Tags: ios, xcode

I was trying to run my app on my iphone to test it, but got this error:

> error: failed to launch '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/*some numbers*/*app name*.app' -- iPhone *name* has denied the launch request.

I found some ways to solve this problem but they did't work
I tried to:

- reinstall the app
- recreate the Provisioning Profile file
- delete the Developer Certificate from Keys so that it will recreate certificate
- reinstall the Xcode
- Setting 'Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority' trust mode from 'Always trust' to 'System defaults'.

The only way to run the app on iPhone is to disable "debug executable" in scheme, but that is not the best solution because I can't use debugger, maybe there is better solution for this problem?

Comment: are you sure you are not signing with a distribution certificate?

Comment: @Sulthan how I can check that?

Comment: Signing Certificate Iphone Developer: *email*(some letters and numbers)

Comment: Got exactly the same problem here since yesterday, haven't figured out why this happened...

Comment: I have exactly the same problem since Apple did something wrong with their automatic code signing (see also this related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55132628/provisioning-profile-doesnt-include-the-application-identifier-and-keychain-acc).

Comment: I have the following scenario: I connect my device to my Mac, open the "Console.app" and set filter by "Errors and Faults". Now, if I want to run the app I see the following message in the console: `SpringBoard [bundleidentifier] Provision violated for watchdog process-exit: <FBSProcessResourceProvision: 0x2812ee680; allowance: <; FBSProcessResourceAllowance; type: realTime; timeValue: 20.0s>; violated: YES> SpringBoard Not terminating [bundleidentifier] for violated provision because: "process is being debugged"`. In order to find this message quickly search for your bundle-identifier.

Comment: Hello everyone, I've created a StackOverflow room to chat about the "iPhone has denied launch request" issue: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190218/iphone-has-denied-the-launch-request-issue

Comment: Every free account seems to have this problem right now. My friends experience the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a free developer account, here is the solution:

Xcode -> preferences -> manage certificates -> bottom plus sign -> iOS Development -> donwload manual certificates.

Under general, go to signing -> change team to none then go back to your development account.

Comment: I just tried, no luck, still think it's Apple server's problem..

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked! Now everything launch perfect!

Comment: Holy crap this method actually worked! By far the most easiest way!!!