# over-the-air ipa download crashes on splash

Tags: ios, angular, nativescript

I created an app with Nativescript + Angular, the app is running fine on the simulator and when the app is running using 'tns run ios' on my connected iPhone. However when archiving the project to an .ipa and use a link to download the app from my server it crashes or gets stuck on the splash screen. The console doesn't really show any errors.

I've archived the app using Nativescript Sidekick, NS CLI and Xcode but all methods result in the same error. I'm using a developing provision profile that shows no errors in Xcode when assigned manually.

Does anyone have experience with this problem and knows how to fix it?

Comment: Which version of {N} you are using?

Comment: I'm using tns-ios version 5.4.2

Comment: Were you able to check the crash logs from Xcode?

Comment: I'm getting the same error as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52722517/ios-provision-violated-for-watchdog-scene-create-using-pushkit in my console. If you need them I can send my Xcode crash logs tomorrow...

Comment: Here's a crash rapport: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/schedules-912ea.appspot.com/o/nsschedules-2019-06-22-200447.crash?alt=media&token=7851e5cf-8070-4090-84ed-af161a8a2f3b

Comment: Are you using any specific plugins / frameworks that is initiated upon launch?

Comment: I'm not requiring any plugins in my main.ts but of course some later on

Comment: I've solved it. Apparently tns build includes hmr which caused the crash, disabling it solved my problem. Thanks for your help!